# How to replace unicode Chinese characters in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

say I have a string like this

```
example = u"这是一段很蛋疼的中文"
```

I wanna replace `蛋` with `egg`, how can I finish this?

It seems `example.replace()` is useless. 
And I tried regex, using `re.match(u"蛋", "")` returns none.

I searched a lot, it seems I should use method like `.decode`, but still it doesn't work, even `example.replace(u"\u86CB", "egg")` is useless.

So is there a way to process Chinese characters?

Comment: Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: It works fine to me(I'm using Python3.5). The replace function does not change the original string. If you want to change the original string, you should use `example = example.replace(u'蛋', 'egg')`.

Comment: If you aren’t using it already, you should definitely switch to Python 3.

Comment: @TsReaper you are right, that's it! I'm so stupid:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the output as below in Python3 .

```
>>> import re
>>> example = u"这是一段很蛋疼的中文"
>>> re.search(u'蛋',example)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(5, 6), match='蛋'>

>>> example.replace('蛋','egg')
'这是一段很egg疼的中文'
>>> re.sub('蛋','egg',example)
'这是一段很egg疼的中文'

>>> example.replace(u"\u86CB", "egg")
'这是一段很egg疼的中文'
>>> re.match('.*蛋',example)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='这是一段很蛋'>
```

`re.match` will try to match the string from the beginning, so it will return `None` in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's because I tried my regex in [regex tester](https://regex101.com/), now I know, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this within `Python2`:

Edit: Adding a correct encoded source file that has a coding spec also using `unicode literals` will solve the issue.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

example = u"这是一段很蛋疼的中文"
print example.replace(u"这", u"egg")
# Within Python3
# print(example.replace("这", 'egg'))
```

Output:

```
egg是一段很蛋疼的中文
```

Comment: I'm using Python 3, and I just find out the reason is that the replace function does not change the original string. Thanks a lot!